# Want to MERGE many tables, so want to build generic procedure to achieve this

Tags: oracle, generics, stored-procedures, merge

My terminology will be loose but the point will be clear. I have built a procedure which merges data using Merge Statement. Now my list of tables is growing and I am at a point where I think I need generic function so I just pass table name of source, destination and on condition and can achieve merge.

This will make my code less complex to maintain, otherwise I have to write one procedure per table to make it easy to maintain but still not compact.

Although due to professional reasons a linear code is more efficient as end product but that is less relevant.

Here is my general code.

```
SET DEFINE OFF;
PROMPT drop Procedure XXX_PROJECTS_MERGE;
DROP PROCEDURE CUSTOM.XXX_PROJECTS_MERGE;
PROMPT Procedure XXX_PROJECTS_MERGE;

/***************************************************************************************************
Prompt Procedure XXX_PROJECTS_MERGE;
--
-- XXX_PROJECTS_MERGE  (Procedure)
--
***************************************************************************************************/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CUSTOM.XXX_PROJECTS_MERGE (
   errbuf                   OUT VARCHAR2,
   retcode                  OUT NUMBER,
   x_Start_Period_Name   IN     VARCHAR2)
AS
   x_retcode   NUMBER := 0;
   x_errbuf    VARCHAR2 (200) := NULL;
BEGIN
   -- Update or insert non transactional tables ------------------------------

   -- Refreshing Key Project Table--------------------------------------------------------------------
   FND_FILE.PUT_LINE (FND_FILE.LOG, 'Starting Project Table Refresh Process');

   MERGE INTO CUSTOM.XXX_PROJECT GPRJ
        USING (SELECT ROWID,
                      PROJECT_ID,
                      set of columns
                 FROM PA.PA_PROJECTS_ALL
                WHERE     ORG_ID = 21
                      AND LAST_UPDATE_DATE >=
                             (SELECT MAX (LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
                                FROM CUSTOM.XXX_PROJECT)) OPRJ
           ON (GPRJ.PROJECT_ID = OPRJ.PROJECT_ID AND GPRJ.ROWID = OPRJ.ROWID)
   WHEN MATCHED
   THEN
      UPDATE SET
         GPRJ.NAME = OPRJ.NAME,
         Above set of columns in above update form
   WHEN NOT MATCHED
   THEN
      INSERT     (set of columns)
          VALUES (set of values as selected above);

   COMMIT;
   FND_FILE.PUT_LINE (
      FND_FILE.LOG,
         'Number of Rows Processed or Merged For XXX_PROJECT Table '
      || TO_CHAR (SQL%ROWCOUNT));
END;
/

SHOW ERRORS;
```

Now I want above to be generic procedure where I pass different set of inputs and can run for any table.

Comment: Do all the source and destination tables have the same structure?  If so, why does the `ON` condition need to be dynamic?  That's not a rhetorical question.

Comment: And what exactly is the question ? For now we know that you want to build some procedure that megres many tables. A synax of CREATE PROCEDURE` can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm  A `MERGE` statement is described here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm Please explain what is unclear to you ?

Comment: Matthew McPeak -- Source and Destination tables have the same structure.

Comment: This is more on the lines of what people use in regular DW type of sw. In any DW tool we will just pick a table and we want to know if there is need to refresh or not using some criteria such as date or Unique key. Unique key is known via unique index and that forms the On condition. If unique Index not matched then insert or delete. When we use Date then we are updating and a second Merge can be added which will look for date, after matching key then check if date updated then update all the columns, that also can be found since source and target are same.